# ForEach-Object in Pipeline Not Working

Tags: powershell

Could someone explain to me why the following works

```
$Users = 'First1 Last1','First2 Last2','First3 Last3'

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    (Get-ADUser -Filter *).Where{$_.Name -like "*$User*"}
}
```

but this does not

```
$Users | % { (Get-ADUser -Filter *).Where{$_.Name -like "*$_*"} }
```

I feel like it's essentially the exact same thing but the first commands return data while the second does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same thing, because `.Where{$_.Name -like "*$_*"}` uses the current object variable twice. In `$_.Name` it should refer to the current object from `Get-ADUser`, whereas in `"*$_*"` it should refer to the current string from `$Users`, but actually also refers to the current object from `Get-ADUser`.

Something like this would make the two statements the same:

```
$Users | % { $u = $_; (Get-ADUser -Filter *).Where{$_.Name -like "*$u*"} }
```

Comment: I did not catch that and I really should have.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any reason you know what this would also not work: `$Users | % {Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like "*$_*"}}`

Comment: @Martin I never liked the scriptblock notation for filters very much, because it's really more a string than a scriptblock. In my experience it's usually better to write it that way (`"Name -like '*$_*'"`).

Answer (score 1):

In the second loop variable `$_` starts being the first user of `$Users` array, but it is overridden by the output of `Get-ADUser`.

In other words in the second loop in `{$_.Name -like "*$_*"}` the `*$_*` you think it is equivalent to `$User` it is not.

Comment: This makes it really clear what the problem was.  Thanks.